# Remove two dimentional array elements(except first match) which array specific value are same/unique

Tags: php, arrays, unique

For example, I have an following two dimentional array is below,

```
$a = array(
    "one" => array (
        "id" => 111,
        "name" => "Jhon"
    ),
    "two" => array(
        "id" => 222,
        "name" => "Adam"
    ),
    "three" => array(
        "id" => 111,
        "name" => "Mark"
    ),
    "four" => array(
        "id" => 125,
        "name" => "Jhon"
    ),
    "five" => array(
        "id" => 111,
        "name" => "Jhon"
    ),
    "six" => array(
        "id" => 222,
        "name" => "Rock"
    ),
);
```

I would like to remove array(except first match) which two dimensional array values are same/unique.
For example, I would like to remove all of the arrays(except first match) which `id` keys values are same.
As, array `id` keys values `111`(has array count 3) and `222`(has array count 2).
So after removing the unique key `id` the result array should be following,

```
$a = array(
    "one" => array (
        "id" => 111,
        "name" => "Jhon"
    ),
    "two" => array(
        "id" => 222,
        "name" => "Adam"
    ),
    "four" => array(
        "id" => 125,
        "name" => "Jhon"
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep an array with added keys. You could use [`array_filter()`](https://php.net/array_filter) to remove unnecessary rows.

Code: ([demo](https://3v4l.org/ide7a))

```
$array = [
    "one"   => ["id" => 111, "name" => "Jhon"],
    "two"   => ["id" => 222, "name" => "Adam"],
    "three" => ["id" => 111, "name" => "Mark"],
    "four"  => ["id" => 125, "name" => "Jhon"],
    "five"  => ["id" => 111, "name" => "Jhon"],
    "six"   => ["id" => 222, "name" => "Rock"],
];

// store added IDs
$added = [];

// filter array (need to pass $added as reference to be updated)
$output = array_filter($array, function($item) use (&$added) 
{
    // shortcut for readability
    $id = $item['id'];  
    // Check if id already exists
    if (isset($added[$id])) { return false; } 
    // add to reference
    $added[$id] = true; 
    // add to final array
    return true; 
});

unset($added); // no longer needed.

var_dump($output);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["one"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(111)
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "Jhon"
  }
  ["two"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(222)
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "Adam"
  }
  ["four"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(125)
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "Jhon"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to complete your task

```
    <?php
$a = array(
    "one" => array (
        "id" => 111,
        "name" => "Jhon"
    ),
    "two" => array(
        "id" => 222,
        "name" => "Adam"
    ),
    "three" => array(
        "id" => 111,
        "name" => "Mark"
    ),
    "four" => array(
        "id" => 125,
        "name" => "Jhon"
    ),
    "five" => array(
        "id" => 111,
        "name" => "Jhon"
    ),
    "six" => array(
        "id" => 222,
        "name" => "Rock"
    ),
);
$unique = [];
$final_array = [];
foreach ($a as  $value) {
    if(in_array($value['id'],$unique)){
        continue;
    }
    else {
        $unique[] = $value['id'];
        $final_array[] = $value;
    }
} 
echo "<pre>";
print_r($final_array);
?>
```

Here i use a unique named array in which i put the unique key and loop through the array if id exsit in unique then it skip that otherwise i add that in final array.
Hope this will sort your problem.

Comment: The keys (`one`,`two` and `four`) are missing in the `final_array`.